# Javascript ES6 - mapping over object to produce a new array loses order of elements in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON object that contains a list of teams, each team has a `teamCrimeCategorySum` which is an object of key value pairs, where each key is a crime category and each value is the total number of crimes in that category. It is arranged alphabetically and looks like this...

```
alcohol:0
animal abuse:0
animal cruelty:0
animal neglect:0
assault:7
attempted murder:0
battery:1
```

I am looping over that to get an array of just the values like so...

```
teamList.map(team => {
  const newArray = Object.keys(team['teamCrimeCategorySum']).map(key => {
    return team['teamCrimeCategorySum'][key]
  })
})
```

This will produce an array where the original order is lost. The above object is producing this...

```
[18, 6, 1, 1, 7, 2, 3, ...]
```

I want to retain the order, such that the above object should instead produce...

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1, ...]
```

Comment: Object properties don't have an order. You can call `Object.keys(o).sort(fn).map`

Comment: That solved it! Thank you! I didn't realize there was no order as when I logged it to the console, it was displayed alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to generate an array retaining the original order from object

```
  const newArray = [];
  for ( let key in tempList) {
         if(tempList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                newArray.push(tempList[key]);
         }
  }
```

Or still if you want to use Object.keys and Array.map, first sort on the keys and then call map like below

```
  Object.keys(tempList).sort().map(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

@rlemon had the right idea. When I was inspecting the object in the console, it was logged in alphabetical order but the object attributes were not stored in alphabetical order. By calling `.sort()`, before `.map()` I was able to establish and then retain the alphabetical order I had intended. The function now looks like this...

```
  teamList.map(team => {
    const newArray = Object.keys(team['teamCrimeCategorySum'])
      .sort()
      .map(key => {
        return team['teamCrimeCategorySum'][key]
      })
    return [`${team.name}`, ...newArray, '']
  })
```